# Flexmojos 4.2-beta mergeResourceBundle

Tags: flexmojos, flex-mojos

What is new command for flexmojos 3.8

```
<mergeResourceBundle>true</mergeResourceBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

http://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/maven-sites/flexmojos/4.0-RC2/compile-swf-mojo.html#includeResourceBundles

```
includeResourceBundles:

A list of resource bundles to include in the output SWC
Equivalent to -include-resource-bundles

Usage:
<includeResourceBundles>
  <rb>SharedResources</rb>
  <rb>Collections</rb>
</includeResourceBundles>
```